# PayPal Button Formatting Incorrectly

Tags: html, paypal

For some reason, the image itself is separate from the link.  I'm not sure why they are being shown as two separate entities?

Here is the code I currently have:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="BE75X4GV7SK4S">
<input type="image" src="http://imgur.com/cbEsYe0"><img 
src="http://i.imgur.com/cbEsYe0.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, 
easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" 
width="1" height="1">
```

The output, as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/Pfugc/

Comment: What *is* the output? Could you add a screenshot for us to see what is happening?

Comment: This is the output: http://jsfiddle.net/Pfugc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the image you used in `image` input is incorrect. Also, you don't need the `img` element, because you already have the image input.

**Corrected [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pfugc/1/)**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="BE75X4GV7SK4S">
<input type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/cbEsYe0.png">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  Odd, considering it was PayPal's code!